# Why did they send Ward in to capture Lorelei?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of Shield*, Coulson's team tries to capture Lorelei with the help of Lady Sif. They knew going in that she can control men, so why didn’t they send a team of women instead of sending in men who can be controlled?

Comment: When one thinks about it, that does not make much sense, hmmm? In fairness, with strong-willed men her voice is not sufficient, and she has to touch them in order to control them. Maybe they thought it would not come to that.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of a Watsonian explanation, all I can think of is that direct confrontation with Lorelei was to be avoided if at all possible. The S.H.I.E.L.D. agents were ordered to remain outside while Sif confronted their foe. As a female Asgardian. she was best-equipped to fight her. They were there to provide backup if necessary,  or if Lorelei tried to flee.

In addition,  Lorelei requires physical contact in order to control strong-willed men. I suppose this description might apply to most agents, since it was the case with Ward. The reasoning might have been that if an Asgardian gets close enough to a normal human to touch them, they will be as good as eliminated from the fight whether they are mind-controlled or not, since an Asgardian can easily kill a human in one blow.

That said, I do not think there is a satisfactory in-universe explanation. Of course it would have been more sensible to send in a team of female agents to back up Sif. Why take the risk of some of the agents being insufficiently strong-willed, and being controlled by her voice? Further, even if physical contact would mean  incapacitation in any case, a dead ally is less dangerous than one who will fight against you, as Ward's case demonstrates quite clearly. In fact, in Ward's case it would have been, albeit by pure chance, *significantly* better for all concerned if he had died instead.

However,  ultimately, the show focuses on the main team, not S.H.I.E.L.D as a whole. So even if it would make sense for none of them (with the possible exception of Agent May) to go to confront Lorelei, they have to be at the center of the action. Further,  to drive the plotline along Ward had to be controlled. This also explains why they did not take other sensible precautions,  like earplugs (so as to be less likely to hear her), or abandoning ground support in favor of aerial support (so as to be less likely to hear her/be touched by her/torn into little bits).